# Magento 2.2 : requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement

Tags: php, installation, magento2.2

Magento 2.2 **should be working with php 7.1**, why do I get this error and how should I fix it ?

> magento@me-dev:/var/www/html/me$ composer require
>   magento2translations/language_zh_cn:dev-master
>       ./composer.json has been updated
>       Loading composer repositories with package information
>       Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>       Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> ```
>   Problem 1
>     - magento/framework 100.0.18 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>     - magento/framework 100.1.9 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not
> ```
>
> satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.1.8 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not
>   satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.0.17 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.0.16 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.1.7 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not
>   satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.1.6 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not
>   satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.0.15 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.1.5 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not
>   satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.0.14 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.1.4 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not
>   satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.0.13 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.1.3 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not
>   satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.1.2 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not
>   satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.0.12 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.1.1 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.0.11 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.0.10 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.1.0 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.0.9 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.0.8 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.0.7 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.0.6 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.0.5 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.0.4 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.0.3 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento/framework 100.0.2 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
>           - magento2translations/language_zh_cn dev-master requires magento/framework ~100.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2,
>   100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.1.0, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.1.1, 100.0.12, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.0.13, 100.1.4, 100.0.14, 100.1.5, 100.0.15, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.0.18].
>           - Installation request for magento2translations/language_zh_cn dev-master -> satisfiable by
>   magento2translations/language_zh_cn[dev-master].
>   Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another language pack worked just fine for Chinese language and is even more up-to-date:

```
composer require mageplaza/magento-2-chinese-language-pack:dev-master
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work, you can install pack manually as follows.

Refer: https://github.com/Magento2Translations/language_zh_cn

```
To install this language package manually you need access to your server file system.

Download the zip file here.
Upload the contents to <your magento path>/app/i18n/magento2translations/language_zh_cn.
The composer files should then be located like this <your magento path>/app/i18n/magento2translations/zh_CN/zh_CN.csv.
Go to your Magento admin panel and clear the caches.
```

Comment: "php -v" gives me "PHP 7.1.11-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)"

Comment: You can install language pack manually as updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your update, however, this language pack is often updated, this is why I'd prefer to install it with composer, to make updates easier.